# Call RESTful service with client certificate in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, https, cryptography, xamarin.forms, bouncycastle

**Summary**
I am writing a Xamarin.Forms app that needs to make requests to a REST Api. It needs to use a client certificate to establish 2-way ssl when it talks to the backend.

I would like all of this to be done in a PCL *if possible.* What is the best way to do this?

**What I have so far**
Xamarin.Forms can not include the package `System.Net.Security`. Because of this, I can not use the normal HttpClient from `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` with client certificates. So I need a different cryptography package, and a different http client that is compatible with this package.

I have found the Bouncy Castle distribution for C#, which seems to be able to handle creating and managing the client certificate. But I have not found an http client that can actually use an `Org.BouncyCastle.X509X509Certificate` to set up 2-way SSL.

**Edit**
So it seems there is no way to use client certificates in shared code (please enlighten me if I'm wrong!). I will have to use DependencyService to create an iOS and an Android implementation of the library, using different HTTP-stacks.

Comment: AFAIK, your edit is correct, there is no option to use client certificate in PCL

Comment: We got the same answer from the developers on Xamarin, unfortunately. So we are going with 3 platform specific implementations to see how much time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you feel about PCL. I wrote this library which is a .NET Standard library that also targets PCL so that it can be used with Xamarin Forms:

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net/overview

There are several samples on getting this to run with Xamarin Forms. As for using the certificate as you mentioned, I'm not sure that you need to do anything special, but I could be wrong. If you can tell me a bit more about what is necessary to use this certificate in particular, I could look at adding the functionality to the library.